# Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 gets frozen

Tags: google-chrome, freeze, ubuntu-gnome

I use Ubuntu-Gnome 16.04 and it got frozen many times. I am tired of this problem.

I think **Google Chrome** forces it to freeze!

System full information `lshw`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24103045/

I do not have any Graphic Card may it help... I really do not know how to fix it but i have this problem from Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What do you mean by I don't have any graphics card?

Comment: @George mean i use mother board internal graphic card.

Comment: This happens for me as well, the HD blink light goes crazy, and I just have to wait 2-10min for it to stop.  It will happen when I open a new tab at random when I've already had a bunch of tabs open.  If I notice it and close the tab before it entirely slows down, it can be prevented, then I go to tab task manager and kill a few windows that I'll get back to later and I can open a new tab again.

Comment: I am tired of this. Please help me before i come back to windows. It really make me sad... Is not any way to solve this big problem?